# Error when trying to access my application in JBoss AS 7.1

Tags: java, jboss, jndi, jboss7.x

I recently migrated my application from JBoss AS 4.2.1 to JBoss AS 7.1, but I am not being able to access the application vua http request since I am getting the below error:

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to instantiate Action, payment.PaymentBean,  defined for 'prepayment' in namespace '/payment'javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.TPGWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader - action - vfs:/content/TPGWeb.war/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:26:64
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:518)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:421)
```

root cause

```
Unable to instantiate Action, payment.PaymentBean,  defined for 'prepayment' in namespace '/payment'javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.TPGWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader - action - vfs:/content/TPGWeb.war/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:26:64
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:360)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.access$000(DefaultActionInvocation.java:38)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$1.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:78)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.<init>(DefaultActionInvocation.java:70)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.<init>(DefaultActionInvocation.java:66)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:189)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:41)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:497)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:421)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.TPGWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader
utils.ResourceCenter.lookupGatewaySecurityBean(ResourceCenter.java:76)
payment.PaymentBean.<init>(PaymentBean.java:39)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:121)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:152)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:141)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:111)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:270)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:360)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.access$000(DefaultActionInvocation.java:38)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$1.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:78)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.<init>(DefaultActionInvocation.java:70)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.<init>(DefaultActionInvocation.java:66)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:189)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:41)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:497)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:421)
```

root cause

```
javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.TPGWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader
org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactoryBuilder.createInitialContextFactory(InitialContextFactoryBuilder.java:64)
javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:681)
javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:240)
javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:192)
utils.ResourceCenter.lookupGatewaySecurityBean(ResourceCenter.java:66)
payment.PaymentBean.<init>(PaymentBean.java:39)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:121)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:152)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:141)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:111)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:270)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:360)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.access$000(DefaultActionInvocation.java:38)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$1.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:78)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.<init>(DefaultActionInvocation.java:70)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.<init>(DefaultActionInvocation.java:66)
com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:189)
org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:41)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:497)
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:421)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final logs.
JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final
```

Comment: where is the location of deployment as in jb7 , we deploy differently

Comment: my application is deployed in standalone/deployments in jboss 7.1

Comment: then you need to re-check the code

Comment: Are your ports and socket bindings open and accessible? Are your security policies configured and open to your app? Has the application successfully deployed (try deploying via the Management Console or CLI rather than the Deployment Scanner)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add "Dependencies: org.jboss.remote-naming" to META-INF/manifest.mf of your .WAR file. This will load org.jboss.remote-naming module and eliminate "Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory" exception. Details here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7

use jboss-ejb-client.properties file and place it to WEB-INF folder vs content like this:

```
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false 
remote.connections=default 
remote.connection.default.host=your host
remote.connection.default.port=your port
remote.connection.default.username=you user
remote.connection.default.password=you password
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
```

and lookup this way:

```
Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
jndiProps.puy(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, JBOSS_USER);
jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, JBOSS_PWD);
jndiProps.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://yourhost:yourport");
InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
YourRemote remote=(YourRemote)initialContext.lookup("java:/app-name/ejb-jar-name/YourBean!package.YourRemote");
```

For details see:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI

Good luck!

Comment: I love you, after wasting 6 hour you saved me.

Answer (score 0):

From post above... "Add "Dependencies: org.jboss.remote-naming" to META-INF/manifest.mf of your .WAR file."

Thanks so much for the above help.  It got me a step closer to migrating to JBoss EAP 6.

An alternative to above, if you have a War file that has to be deployed on non-JBoss servers, is to add the following to the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file.

That has the benefit of separating out the JBoss specific elements to their own JBoss specific files.

```
<sub-deployment name="yourWebApp.war">
    <dependencies>
    <module name="org.jboss.remote-naming" />
    </dependencies>
</sub-deployment>
```

regards,
Owen