# Cannot instantiate EJBs with JBoss AS 7.1

Tags: java, ejb, jboss7.x

I defined an EJB and I'm trying to use it from another war:

In `ejb-api.jar`:

```
@Remote
public interface Example {
    // ...
}
```

---

In `ejb-impl.war` (uses `ejb-api.jar`):

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "ExampleEjb")
public class ExampleBean implements Example {
    // ...
}
```

---

In `ejb-user.war` (uses `ejb-api.jar`):

```
@WebServlet("/ejbuser")
public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(...) throws Exception {
        Example example = null;
        try {
            InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
            example = (Example)context.lookup("ExampleEjb");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I deployed `ejb-impl.war` and `ejb-user.war` to an instance of JBoss AS 7.1.
If I put all classes in the same war file, then the EJB is found. But this way, it's not (I get a `NamingException`).

Furthermore, if I add a `jndi.properties` file with these contents...

```
java.naming.factory.initial = org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url = remote://localhost:4447
jboss.naming.client.ejb.context = true
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs = org.jboss.ejb.client.naming
```

... then I get this kind of warning:

```
16:55:46,268 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-7) javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.example.war:main" from Service Module Loader: javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011843: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.example.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactoryBuilder.createInitialContextFactory(InitialContextFactoryBuilder.java:64)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:681) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:192) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration.processJndiEntries(WebConfiguration.java:687) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration.<init>(WebConfiguration.java:134) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration.getInstance(WebConfiguration.java:194) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:163) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [@Stateless' documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Stateless.html), "Application servers are not required to support any particular form or type of mapped name, nor the ability to use mapped names." Therefore, it's not a good idea to use it to change the bean's mapped name IMHO.

Let's try

1. removing mappedName from @Stateless
2. **EDITED:** using ExampleBean's name in the java:global namespace:
   `java:global[/application name]/module name/enterprise bean name[/interface name]`

[Further reading about portable JNDI syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html#girgn)

**EDITED:**
You're deploying both of your modules to the same app server, aren't you? Then, you don't need a jndi.properties file, let's try not using it.

Comment: I removed the mapped name and I tried names from the list that appears in the server log when the bean is deployed. It still doesn't work. I suppose there's something wrong with the JNDI configuration file

Comment: Yes, both modules are deployed to the same app server. I finally managed to inject my ebj by putting everything in an ear (without any jndi.properties) and using the @EJB annotation instead of context.lookup(). I will also try again outside the ear.

Comment: What exception do you get when your modules are not in an EAR and you're trying to lookup with your bean's java:global namespace name e.g. java:global/ejb-impl/ExampleBean?

Comment: With "java:global/ejb-impl/ExampleBean" i was getting "javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ejb-impl/ExampleBean -- service jboss.naming.context.java.global.ejb-impl.ExampleBean". But I tried with one of the names from the server log, "java:global/example-impl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ExampleBean!example.Example" (this time without jndi.properties) - and it worked. Many thanks for the help, Csaba!

Answer (score 0):

Add "Dependencies: org.jboss.remote-naming" to META-INF/manifest.mf of your .WAR file. This will load org.jboss.remote-naming module and eliminate "Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory" exception. Details [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7)

The answer on the same problem you could [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12684762/1713511)